# Indentation went crazy in Emacs Haskell Mode

Tags: haskell, emacs

After a recent full-system update I've noticed that indentation in Haskell mode has become really strange:

```
import Data.Ratio
    _
```

Underscore signifies position of caret after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, i.e. in my case at 4 column. It's really unbearable because it goes to column 4 every time I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I'm sure it has nothing to do with Haskell Mode itself, since it has no fresh updates and it worked perfectly until now. However, there seems to be new version of Emacs: [24.4](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), so I'm wondering if they changed something that would cause this bug.

Does anyone else encounter the problem? Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: I had not even seen that a new version is out - thanks for pointing this out. I guess I'll wait a while before I get 24.4

Comment: There is a section "Editing Changes ... Indentation" here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/news/NEWS.24.4 - I wonder if this is the culprit - can you try to disable the `electric-indent-mode`? (you know `M-x electric-indent-mode` and look for the result

Comment: @CarstenKönig, yeah it disabled this behavior! I'm gonna add some lines into my '.emacs' to disable it on startup.

Comment: Is it ok if I add this as an answer?

Comment: @CarstenKönig, Of course, I'll gladly accept it! I've disabled the mode by adding `(electric-indent-mode 0)` into my `.emacs` file.

Comment: Your answer says something about "indentation has become strange" but your example only talks about the position of the cursor.  Has indentation actually changed?

Comment: @Stefan, well, I think it's OK to say that indentation changed, if we mean certain behavior of an editor such as Emacs by the term, and I think that this is the case. Dictionary says that "indentation - 1. the action of indenting or the state of being indented", so if the way of how some action is performed has changed, we can say that the the action itself has changed. Isn't it?

Comment: My question was not arguing against your use of the term.  I was just wondering whether there was any further problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems there was a new indentation mode **`electric-indent-mode`** introduced with 24.4
(see ["Editing Changes ... Indentation" section here](http://gnu.org/software/emacs/news/NEWS.24.4))

You can disable by (for the session)

```
M-x electric-indent-mode
```

or adding something like

```lisp
(electric-indent-mode 0)
```

to your `.emacs` file.

You can disable it just on `haskell-mode` too with this:

```lisp
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook
          (lambda () (electric-indent-local-mode 0)))
```

Comment: Rather than hope some expert can comment, why didn't you actually just try it?  I'm pretty sure you'll soon find that it doesn't do what you think (it re-enables electric-indent-mode globally whenever you visit a haskell file).

Comment: @Stefan because I don't have this version of emacs on my system and based on this: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minor-Modes.html#Minor-Modes it *might* work but it is not 100% clear for me. But maybe you can tell me how you can get a hook for a major mode that disables the minor mode and I will happily edit the answer - or better: make your own answer and I will happily upvote and remove the offending sections from mine